# Cyclotomic extension contained in a sequence of Kummer extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $L$ the $n$-th cyclotomic extension of $K$. Show that there is a sequence of Kummer extensions $E_0 = K \subseteq E_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq E_r$ such that $L$ is contained in $E_r$.

My thoughts so far are this. We can assume $n \geq 3$ immediately, as otherwise we just have that $L = K$ and so we can just take any Kummer extension of $K$. Now, for the $n=3$ case, one can just let $E_1 = L$ because then as $\text{char} K = 0$, $\text{Gal}(L/K) \cong \mathbb{Z}_1 \text{ or } \mathbb{Z}_2$ is cyclic and $K$ contains a $2$nd primitive root of unity (namely $-1$), $K \subseteq E_1$ is Kummer and certainly $L \subseteq E_1$. It seems natural to proceed by induction (although we assume a bit more than what we actually need).

Supposing that we denote $L_n$ as the $n$-th cyclotomic extension of $K$, and for $n$ we have a sequence of Kummer extensions $K = E_0 \subseteq E_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq E_{n-2}$ such that $E_{k-2}$ contains all the $m$-th roots of unity for  for $2 \leq m \leq k \leq n$. We now want to adjoin a primitive $(n+1)$-th root unity to $E_{n-2}$, say by letting $E_{n-1}$ to be the splitting field of $t^n - 1$ over $E_{n-2}$. We know that $E_{n-2} \subseteq E_{n-1}$ is Galois - so all that remains is to show that the extension is cyclic. I feel that it should be because the only new roots of unity being added are primitive - however I can't translate this feeling into a proof.

If this approach is correct so far, could someone explain how to finish it off? And, if for some reason, this approach is doomed to fail, could someone point me in a correct direction?

Comment: It is not always true that the $3$rd cyclotomic extension of a field has Galois group of order two over that field: maybe the cube roots of unity are all in the field originally.

Comment: @KCd Good point - I assume that particular part can be rectified just by saying that $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ is either isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_1$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (or just say it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2$)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prove that $E_{n-1}/E_{n-2}$ is a cyclic extension. Since $Gal(E_{n-1}/E_{n-2})$ is embedded in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, it is an abelian group of order less than n. In addition, $E_{n-2}$ contains all primitive m-th roots for m less than n by induction hypothesis. Thus, $E_{n-1}/E_{n-2}$ is a Kummer extension by definition.